# The indefinite article before nouns made of verbs with the "ing" ending

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I have come across it in the program [6 minute english](https://youtu.be/Cn0oOdwryPo?t=134) from BBC. It is at 2 minute and 17 second. Here it goes:

> He says a white lie is just a distortion of the truth. *Distortion* here means (**a**) changing or bending of the truth.

Why was *a* used before the word *changing*. Would it be grammatical if I the speaker omitted the article?

Comment: In the exact context as given here, the definite article *(**a**)* and the indefinite article *(**the**)* AND the "zero article" (nothing at all) are all perfectly valid. It's really just a stylistic choice which of those three options to use (and you could repeat the article before the second noun ***bending***, but most writers usually wouldn't).

Comment: It is a stylistic choice as pointed out above. It is also situational.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - note that you got "definite" and "indefinite" backwards in your comment.

Comment: Is this the whole sentence?  I wonder whether it isn't a list, as in *distortion here means (a) changing or bending of the truth, and (b) [something else].*

Answer (score 1):

"changing the truth" is a verb statement. "changing of the truth" is a noun statement.

Two valid sentences: "Distortion here means bending the truth". "Distortion here means a changing of the truth".